# Why do I keep getting "The directory name is invalid"?

Tags: directory

I have been trying to get this to work for so long, yet it won't work. I am trying to navigate from Downloads to a certain folder so I can do something, however it just keeps saying "The directory name is invalid".

`C:User/Damien/Downloads>cd JKLMBombpartyHelper-master.zip` is what I am trying to do.

Does anyone know a certain reason of why this continues to occur?

Answer (score 0):

`JKLMBombpartyHelper-master.zip` is not a directory, it's a zip, make sure to specify the relative/absolute directory you wanna cd into

Comment: Would extracting the zip work better?

Comment: what do you mean? do you want to cd (change directory) or Unzip a file?

Comment: I know how to cd, and I know how to unzip, I was asking if it would stop giving me the message if I unzipped the file, and then tried to cd.

Comment: of course because when you unzip it it will become a directory